# Pythonic Way of Getting Network Interfaces and Submitting Configuration Changes

Tags: python, network-programming

I need to programmatically manipulate Linux host device IP addresses. I have not found any Python libraries that provide this functionality. I think that what I'm after may be provided in the `ip` CLI tool, but am hoping for a Pythonic solution not involving `subprocess`.

*This is not a web scraping issue, so I am not looking for proxy-related solutions.*

The use-case is providing a web interface on a Raspberry Pi from within a Docker container so that the user can set the device's IP address in a simple HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

The `py-ip-command` might help you. It allows you run the command and get the output as a pythonic object, that can be easily accessed.
You can find it on PyPi:
https://pypi.org/project/py-ip-command/

Comment: This looks like it could have been a cool package, but it only supports two output commands and doesn't accept configuration changes like I am looking for. Development on the package seems to have halted in 2019. Thanks for the suggested though.